# How to pass extra parameter in to kms plugin

Tags: kurento

**What i do:**

1.I generated so for the kms-opencv-plugin-sample(using link  https://github.com/Kurento/kms-opencv-plugin-sample.)

2.To call the opencv-plugin from client-js,i modified crowddetector-client-js "https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-js/tree/master/kurento-crowddetecto‌​r"(renamed the folder name to kurento-module-opencvpluginsample).

3.Modification i have done:

```
   1.Updated the opencv js file path in the index.html 
   2.Replaced the "kurento-module-crowddetector" to "kurento-module-opencvpluginsample"(with the newly generated JS files) 
   3.Modified the module name in the index.js 
   4.Removed the old reference to crowddetector.
```

4.I started the "KurentoMediaServer" and then "http-server",load the page in browser

```
  http://10.10.1.3:8080/index.html?ws_uri=ws://10.10.1.3:8888/kurento#
```

5.It **works** successsfully.

6.Also i tried with replace  the opencv face detection code with the default given code in opencv-plugin-sample,It also works.

**What i need to know:**

1.What i need to do,if i want to add extra arguments in the process()?

2.What i have to do if i want to add another method in the cpp?

Answer (score 4):

Process method cannot be be modified, you need to have object attributes modified by properties or methods in `kmd.json` file. This way an API is created that can be accessed from remote clients.

Just modify `kmd.json`, this will generate the basic stub in c++. Solve compilation issues and then use this properties according to your needs.

See how [this method](https://github.com/Kurento/kms-opencv-plugin-sample/blob/master/src/server/interface/opencvpluginsample.OpencvPluginSample.kmd.json#L20) works in example filter. The same can be also done with properties instead of methods.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,@santoscadenas

Comment: yes,if you get a chance pls join the room http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36966/kurento-media-server

Comment: Followed the example opencv filter and works well with int or double, however creating a method which takes a String generates an error !

Comment: @geekInMe can you clarify a little bit more how does it fail? Ideally opening a new question if explanation is too long