# Return the value from the method in Kurento Media Server

Tags: kurento

**What i do:**

1.I downloaded the kms-opencv-plugin-sample from the link(https://github.com/Kurento/kms-opencv-plugin-sample).

2.Replace the opencv sample in the process method with the opencv **FaceDetection**.

3.Also make some changes with reference to the link [How to pass extra parameter in to kms plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36015747/how-to-pass-extra-parameter-in-to-kms-plugin) and successfully run the facedetection.

4.I also passes a argument to the method,by modifying the `kmd.json` file

**What i need to do:**

1.In the face detection it shows the output mat,Also i need to return the faceRect value(rectangle points)

2.So i need to return the value in the response

Answer (score 3):

You can raise an event in that case because the `process` method signature cannot be changed.

From the [kurento documentation](http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.org/en/stable/mastering/develop_kurento_modules.html#examples):
There are a lot of examples of how to define methods, parameters or **events** in all our public built-in modules:

- [kms-pointerdetector](https://github.com/Kurento/kms-pointerdetector/tree/master/src/server/interface)
- [kms-crowddetector](https://github.com/Kurento/kms-crowddetector/blob/master/src/server/interface/crowddetector.CrowdDetectorFilter.kmd.json)
- [kms-platedetector](https://github.com/Kurento/kms-platedetector/blob/master/src/server/interface/platedetector.PlateDetectorFilter.kmd.json)

**Edit:**

An example for raising an event can be found [here](https://github.com/Kurento/kms-filters/blob/master/src/server/implementation/objects/ZBarFilterImpl.cpp#L102). As you can see, once the event is defined in the kmd, you can create it and send it using the signal object.

In the case of a OpenCV plugin, you need a little bit more of work, because you need a reference to the endpoint object from the opencv class that is doing the process.

Comment: @ santoscadenas,Thanks for the reply
can u explain how to raise an event?

Comment: if you get a chance pls join the room 
http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36966/kurento-media-server

Comment: I checked the above modules,it uses only gstreamer module.But i have created opencv module .Is there any documentation or example to handle events in the opencv module or what are the changes I have to done with reference to the gstreamer module.

Comment: The idea is the same, just try to apply this examples to what you have. The c++ part of the modules is similar.

Comment: In the OpenCV module implementation documentation, they mentioned that "The first two files should not be modified. The last two files will contain the logic of your module"(Ref: **http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.org/en/stable/mastering/develop_kurento_modules.html#opencv-module**). But in the given example, the first two files only generated and modified for the Events (Because GStreamer module)

Comment: Can you please share any documentation to create the Event to send response to the client from Both GStreamer(we have sample already) and OpenCV modules. This will be helpful for us and if someone try to do this in future. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please clarify the below question. I am using OpenCV module now. Do I need to use GStreamer module to create the Events?